# Javascript/Angular - Properties and methods of JS Object

Tags: javascript, angular, service, controller, factory

JavaScript objects are containers for named values called properties or methods, but I want to know if when I send some object into a $http.post of Angular, does it recognize only the properties?

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp
Example of what I mean:

//TestFactory

```
return function(){
        {name: 'test1', getName :  function(){ return this.name }
       };
```

//TestController

```
vm.Test = new TestFactory();
TestService.Save(vm.Test);
```

//TestService

```
function Save(testdata){
 $http.post('url/test/save', testdata)
}
```

Comment: `getName` is also a property.  `JSON.stringify` either ignores property values that are functions, or converts them to null, so they won't typically get passed to your server code.

Comment: James, thanks for your reply, it helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see what the post payload will be, you can

```
console.log( JSON.stringify( test_data ) );
```

You'll see something like this

```
{
  'name': 'test1',
  'getName': '[Function]'
}
```